# Inverse an invertible binary matrix plus a constant scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Assume I have a matrix $A$  composed of only $0$'s and $1$'s. It is known that A is invertible.

Now, consider a shifted version of this matrix denoted by B. B is formed by adding a constant $C$ to all the entries of A. i.e., $B_{ij}=A_{ij}+C \hspace {0.5cm} \forall i,j.$

What can I say about the invertibility of $B$?

I guess is that it is invertible. But,  I don't see a way to prove this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $$ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\qquad C=\begin{bmatrix} -1/2&-1/2\\-1/2&-1/2\end{bmatrix}. $$
Then $A$ is invertible, while
$$
A+C=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2&-1/2\\-1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not invertible.